# Fill combobox via ajax wile opening

Tags: php, html, ajax

i have a table with many rows of data.
Now i have to show detail infos to each row.
i get the details from a webservice so i cant get them before creating the table.

my idea is
i show an empty combobox and fill it(JS,AJAX) by clicking on the combobox-arrow.
is this possible ?

bye jogi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
in your response create
<select>
<option>value1</option>
<option>value2</option>
<option>value3</option>
</select>
```

u have to send your response like this 
then it will serve u